# How do I filter issue comment authors using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, github-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get the list of comments on an issue using GraphQL. I'm able to get comments by everyone but not only by author.

My code:

```
query {
      repository(name: "maintainer-bot", owner: "Xenfo") {
        issue(number: 16) {
          comments(first: 10) {
            nodes {
              author {
                login
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

My question: How would I filter the comments returned so that only the user with the name Xenfo has his comments returned?

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: That query doesn't seem to have been implemented. I'm filtering client-side.